# Google cloud compute vm automatically getting created after destroying

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, terraform, coreos, tectonic-coreos

I was trying to install tectonic on a coreos image in Google Compute Engine. It didn't work out well & I made some configuration mistakes so I tried to delete the VM but now it keeps on creating these instances -

[image: instances]

Here are the operations log i found in the google cloud compute admin panel - 
[image: operations]

which suggests that they are in some kind of a target pool which is recreating these instances on deletion.

Can anyone tell how to fix this & permanently delete all the instances.

Comment: Can you try gcloud command to list and delete the target pool? https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/target-pools/

Comment: I did, it says the instance templates are in use & cannot be deleted

Comment: Here is the exact error message if this can help solve the issue - 
"The deletion of the instance group failed. Error: The instance_group_manager resource 'projects/**/urtutors-master-igm-0' is already being used by 'projects/**/global/backendServices/urtutors-api-backend-service'"

Comment: Try to delete its dependents first.

Comment: @DeadMan As I suggested in this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-dev/QKhABK3smhg), you can delete the load balancer and all its resources from this [link](https://console.cloud.google.com/net-services/loadbalancing) before deleting the instance group. Let me know if it solves your issue.

Comment: Yeah, I got it now. thanks for the support!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have discussed this issue at this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-dev/QKhABK3smhg), and it seems you have been using a managed [instance group](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/) with [autoscaler](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/) and [load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/) enabled. The autoscaler is setup to recreate the instances as per the configurations.

In order to delete the entire instance group, you have to delete all resources that are using it first, such as the load balancer, [backend services](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/backend-service#create-backend-service), etc.